# Processing API in Golang Using Query?

Tags: json, api, go

I am trying to process a song using API.I have tried using a specific URL in http.get and further unmarshalling the data but the only element returned in the console is {}. Any help to send me in the right direction is appreciated.

Edit: here is some code. I have this in my main file.

```
var data [2]Data

if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

defer response.Body.Close()
if response.StatusCode != 200 {
    log.Fatal("Didn't get 200")
}

rawData, err := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

json.Unmarshal(rawData, &data)

fmt.Println(data[0])
```

I have a struct created in a separate file for JSON tags/keys.

```
type Data struct {
    SongID          string `json:id`
    Name            string `json:name`
}
```

Comment: Can you show us some of your code so that we can help with specific issues within it? Thx.

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer I have edited with some of the code I have so far. Thanks!

Comment: `json.Unmarshal` returns an error value, you should check if it's `nil` and if it isn't it will tell you what the problem is which will also be the reason you're seeing `{}`.

Comment: ... actually in this case it probably won't say much because your target type `[2]SongData` does not seem to match the json structure that is returned from that url. You need to pass a type to `json.Unmarshal` that matches the json structurally.

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/ZVwNS8bJ6cf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 type data struct {
   Error    bool `json:"error"`
   Response struct {
    Results []struct {
        ID   int    `json:"id"`
        Name string `json:"name"`
    } `json:"results"`
  } `json:"response"`
}
```

This should be the data structure.

1. Use curl to request

   curl  https://searchly.asuarez.dev/api/v1/song/search?query=hello
2. use https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/ to convert the JSON response to Golang struct.

Comment: Your code is okay, just replace the data struct. Instead of using curl just print rawData as string and convert it to struct.